# Save an org-mode buffer when I clock in/out of a task

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, auto-save

I'm using the clocking functionality quite extensively, and I built a number of tools (outside of Emacs) that will look for clocked-in tasks. The problem is that these tools will parse the file on disk, and therefore only pick up the clock entries if the buffer was saved in the meantime. I could just save the buffer manually, but I'm also using `org-mru-clock`, so it might not always be evident which buffer to save.

So I wanted to ask whether there is an easy way to hook into the clock-in/-out events to determine the buffer the task is in, and just save it.

Comment: One idea would be to advise `org-clock-in` and `org-clock-out` to `save-buffer` at the outset, and several examples of how this might work can be found by Googling:   **advice before emacs** ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has cool feature - defadvice. You can surround any function with your own operation.

In this case, something along the lines of

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (defadvice org-clock-in (after org-clock-in-after activate) (save-buffer))
                           (defadvice org-clock-out (after org-clock-out-after activate) (save-buffer))))
```

in your .emacs would make `save-buffer` happen after either clock-in or clockout.

Taken from :

- [defadvice examples](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions)
- [org-mode hooks examples](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-configs/org-config-examples.html)

Comment: Rather than `add-hook` it might be better to use `eval-after-load` so that you don't readvise the function every time you open an org file.

Answer (score 4):

`org-clock-in` and `org-clock-out` have "hooks" associated with them --- lists of extra functions that run whenever you clock in/out.  You can add your own functions (which will be called with no arugment) using `add-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'org-clock-in-hook #'save-buffer)
(add-hook 'org-clock-out-hook #'save-buffer)
```